# I want to use the Chromium Browser. I can't for some reason

Tags: chromium, browser

My processor is a x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have recently downloaded "chomium-browser" although I can not access it's properties. I can NOT use google chrome for what it is. It's basically just an Icon sitting on my app thing.  Please help me.

I'm pretty sure it's installed correctly, it just wont work. :(

This is what happens if I run it from terminal:

[image: chromium-browser error]

Thank you,

Aksana B.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23718/discussion-on-question-by-aksana-i-want-to-use-the-chromium-browser-i-cant-for).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems your user doesn't have permission to access the folder `~/.config/chromium`.

As suggested in [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1623261) at Ubuntu forums, you have to delete this folder and let chromium create the next time you start it.

So type `sudo rm -rf ~/.config/chromium` in a terminal window. Now start your browser normally. The problem should be fixed.

Comment: Just open a terminal window again then type `rm -rf ~/.config/chromium` and then enter.  Once you're done then you just need to start your browser again by running it's launcher in the app bar.

Comment: okay done! What's the next step?

Comment: Have you started your browser? It should start normally.

Comment: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-doQQML3a-Os/VVJw3pm7P0I/AAAAAAAAAFY/ARG4OF83IhQ/w978-h550/nope.png

DARN! This is what I got in reply.

Comment: add a sudo in front of the command and run it again. It should be like `sudo rm -rf ~/.config/chromium`. Tell me if it works.

Comment: Same thing.  I would send another picture, although it's as if it was a replica of the prior one. :/

Comment: You can select and copy the result here. No need to take pictures.

Comment: Type `ll -d ~/.config/chromium` and post the result here too, please.

Comment: result:     


drwx------ 3 root root 4096 May 12 11:41 /home/quantum/.config/chromium/

Comment: Please post the result of `sudo rm -rf ~/.config/chromium`

Comment: OMG YOU FIXED IT :D :D :D THAAAANKS!!! :D

Comment: You're welcome. Accept this one as the answer to your problem so others can make good use. \o/

Comment: Yes I DID instantly :D

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to "vote up" though.

Comment: Don't worry. Just keep leveling your ubuntu skills up! ;)

Comment: LOL, thanks SO much! You have helped me SO much you have no idea.. I really needed this today! I really appreciate your time :)

Comment: Just giving back the help I once received!

Comment: just out of curiosity do have any idea how to work with grub?? I seemed to have removed it trying to retrieve my windows 8 when i ran it along side.. I have that question on my account. i asked it yesterday but i didn't have a good enough answer sadly.  idk maybe since you're such a genius maybe you would know how to help ????

Comment: That is another thread... let's take a look there.

Comment: :D wow, you're so SMART!